# Salesforce Live agent custom message display

Tags: liveagent

How can i display a message to the user when an agent is away in Salesforce Live Agent chat.Where do i need to configure the message?Currently when an agent is away and the user clicks on the chat button,it shows the offline status.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be done. The way Salesforce handles both away and offilne are almost same from user (chat user) point of view. Agents can't accept incoming chats hence the button shows offline status.

[image]

Even in the [addButtonEventHandler](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.live_agent_dev.meta/live_agent_dev/live_agent_automated_chat_invitations_API_addButtonEventHandler.htm) callback function this status is not available. So as of now, it seems this is not exposed to the configuration as well as API.

[image]